# difficulty with adding values from html textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am a newbie to programming...
I have 3 values from a text input.  I want 2 of these values to be stored into separate arrays for later access. finally I want to display a sum of these 3 values in my document. 
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<script>

function displayCurrentBalance() {
  var initialBalance =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("initialBalance").value);

  var inAmounts=[0];
  var outAmounts = [0];
  inAmounts.push(document.getElementById("amountIn").value);
  outAmounts.push(document.getElementById("amountOut").value);

  var sumIn = (inAmounts.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b[1];
  }, 0));
  var sumOut = (outAmounts.reduce(function(c, d) {
    return c + d[1];
  }, 0));

  var result = initialBalance + sumIn - sumOut;
  document.write(result);
};

displayCurrentBalance();

</script>
```

Comment: close your variable statements... `var variable = '';` there is several times you forgot to do so

Comment: fixed it.still doesnt work but thanks

Comment: Could you put this up in a jsFiddle with all of your code?

Comment: Why are you putting a +b[1] and c + d[1] in the functions? try changing that just to a+b and c+d

Answer (score 0):

1. `document.write(result);` will overwrite your document before you even have a chance to enter the values. Make it display a value in another input box, or `alert(result)`.
2. You should probably attach `displayCurrentBalance` to an `onclick` handler of some button, like `<button onclick="displayCurrentBalance()">Calculate</button>`.
3. `document.getElementById("amountIn").value` and similar calls will give you a string. You should use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert it to an integer or a float.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely calling the function before the elements are available in the page. Otherwise the script should be below the elements in the page.

You main problem is how you are using [*reduce*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21). The values returned from the inputs are strings, so convert them to numbers before trying to add them (otherwise you will be concatenating strings, not adding numbers). You should probably validate the values too.

Also, reduce is called with the values of the members of the array, not the array itself (which is the 4th parameter provided to the callback, not the second), so:

```
var sumIn = (inAmounts.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return +a + +b;
}, 0));
```

Modify the other call to *reduce* similarly. I don't think you need to provide an initial value since you initialise the array as `[0]`. Alternatively, keep the initial value in the call and initialise the array as `[]` (i.e. an empty array).

Rather than using *document.write* to display the result, better to write it as the value of a read–only input element so you can update it with subsequent calls as the user modifies the values in the other inputs.